# Capybara not waiting on expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a page with a link that opens a bootstrap modal with a simple input field. I'm having a hard time understanding why Capybara doesn't wait for the modal to open, and fails immediately.

I added `expect(page).to have_content('Did you')` so capybara will wait a few seconds until the modal is shown.
But for some reason it's not waiting and raises `Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: expected to find text "Did you" in ...."`

If I put a sleep of 1 second it will then find the modal, but it's not good enough because then a DB clean callback found in my **spec_helper.rb** is called:

```
config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

This is the spec:

```
RSpec.describe "follower button", type: :request do
  it "sends email #15B to owner", :js do
    using_wait_time 20 do
      FactoryGirl.create(:apartment_with_event)

      visit apartment_path(Apartment.last)
      click_on 'follow-events'
      expect(page).to have_content('Did you')
      within('#follow-events-modal') do
        fill_in 'follower-email-signup-mail', with: 'follower@example.com'
        click_button 'follower-signup-submit'
      end

      expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t("followers.create.title_success"))
      expect(Follower.all.count).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end
```

I also set `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10` in **spec_helper.rb**, even though it should wait for 20 seconds for this example.

Forgot to mention, I'm using **Capybara-wekbit** as the driver.

I really spent hours trying to discover why it's happening, while other examples run just fine.

**UPDATE:**
Adding full backtrace of failure.

```
Failures:

  1) leeron's button sends email #15B to owner
     Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/images/slider/missing.png"
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/rollbar-1.2.13/lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/request_store-1.2.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in `block in call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:43:in `call'
     # /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
     #   expected to find text "Did you" in "...(REMOVED BY ME TO SAVE SPACE)..."
     #   /Users/etaiso/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/dorbel/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:527:in `block in assert_text'

Finished in 3.87 seconds (files took 9.79 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

Comment: which capybara driver do you use: Webkit, Poltergeist, whatever?

Comment: Firstly, your DB clean callback in spec_helper should be added with `append_after` - see https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example - The order the callbacks are run in is critically important and you want the DB clean to be called last.  Second - are there any more details in the complete error message you're getting?  When you say it's not waiting, do you mean it just instantly fails, no 20 second wait and then fail?  If so check your config to make sure that test is actually being run with capybara-webkit  `puts Capybara.current_driver` after the visit

Comment: @itsnikolay i'm using webkit.

Comment: @TomWalpole yes it's instantly fails, i've edited the original post with the full backtrace. Also, the driver is indeed webkit.

Comment: Oh -- your app is throwing a server exception which is causing the text match retries to exit early - either fix the missing image file exception or turn off `Capybara.raise_server_errors`   -- you're better off fixing your exception though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the callback we can see that the actual exception is a routing error from the app.  While Capybara is retrying/waiting on finders and expectations it checks for server thrown errors and if `Capybara.raise_server_errors` is true it will raise them in the test thread so they are visible to tests.  A side-effect of the re-raising of exceptions from the app thread in the test thread is that any current exception in the test thread (such as ExpectationNotMet) which would normally be handled and retried by Capybara gets set by ruby as the nested `cause` of the apps exception.  It isn't really the cause but we can't because of the way Capybara re-raises the server error it shows up there.  You can either set `Capybara.raise_server_errors = false` or better yet, fix the missing image.

Comment: @etaiso https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/1720 will make this clearer in the next Capybara release

Comment: thanks Tom! I was aware of the server error but had no clue it was the reason as Capybara "--- Caused by: ---" misleading me. And +1 for your PR! :)